# Browser slow in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, firefox, chromium, amd-graphics, msi

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in my MSI GX70 laptop with ATI Radeon 8650. I have a ram of 16gb and a swap space of 9.5fb

It is very smooth. However, the Chromium browser gets very slow after a few hours of usage.

I tried many things such

1. Increasing the APT cache limit
2. Disabling smooth scolling
3. Alter swapiness
4. Disabled hardware acceleration

However, none of them seem to have the desired effect. Point 1 did affect my browser speed temporarily but gradually it has no effect. 
I also use a Windows 7 with a Chromium and it works smoothly no matter how long I use it.

I have tried other versions of ubuntu and they seem to work the same way. I tried shifting to Firefox but it gets worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand why but the video links slowed down my browsers, be it Firefox or Chrome.

I took one of the suggestions in the answers and comments (that have been deleted) to use a lightweight browser.

I decided to use Qupzilla just to watch videos and my main browser for the rest, and by browser has not slowed down since then.